# Refer to relative file in jvm.config

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, multi-module

Our artifactory maven repository is accessible only over https, but is using a selfsigned certificate. We want to make it as easy as possible for new developers to onboard so we chose not to add the certificate to the default java keystore.

Instead, I made a new keystore with all our self signed certificates, and checked this in the root of our project in `/project-files/keystore.jks`. I also added `/.mvn/jvm.config`, which sets some project specific jvm options (introduced in [maven 3.3.1](https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/release-notes.html)). My first attempt was

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/project-files/keystore.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password`
```

This works fine if you run maven in the root dir but if I run a single module from its subdirectory, it cannot find the trust store and fails.

I then added a shell variable `PROJECT_BASEDIR`, and the trustStore in my jvm.config became `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=$PROJECT_BASEDIR/project-files/keystore.jks`. However, it still cannot find the trust store. If I look at the process using `ps`, it turns out the variable was not resolved. I also tried `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=${project.parent.basedir}/project-files/keystore.jks`, but that did not work either.

Anybody know a solution for this problem?

Comment: running a single module from its subdirectory is actually not recommended, you should still run it from root directory and only run it via `mvn -pl <module-name>`

Comment: This is a general configuration which means it should be located into the folder where the user settings is located. The simply solution can be read here: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-repository-ssl.html Either via `MAVEN_OPTS` or via `$HOME/.mavenrc` which is intended for such things. The `.mvn/jvm.config` is not the right location for it cause its project specific. This is system specific. In this case I would tend to `.mavenrc`or for windows `$HOME/mavenrc_pre.cmd` ...And there you set `MAVEN_OTPS` accordingly...

Comment: What if I don't want all my projects to use the save javax.net.ssl.trustStore and I'm tired of adding -D to command line every time?

Answer (score 0):

The [**`MNG-5767`**](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5767) feature (*project-specific default jvm options and command line parameters*) is a great feature added to Maven and handy in many cases, however it is still at its basic level, it doesn't provide advanced behaviors (if any required).

It is really powerful when it comes to multi-module projects for common and global configuration because it is also picks up when building a module from its current directory (hence picking `.mvn/jvm.config` of its parent), but it has some limits (according to my tests on latest Maven version **3.3.9**, at the time of writing):

- you can't override values at module level with additional `.mvn/jvm.config`, they will be ignored
- you can't have relative paths and expect to work properly from module directory build, since it will also be used while buiding a module from its directory (again, hence picking up parent `.mvn/jvm.config`) and as such break relative paths resolution
- you can't have maven properties placeholders since they would not be replaced (too early in the maven build phase to perform it)

---

In this case and actually in general the advice would be to build the module from the root/parent folder using [reactor options](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html) and specifying via project list (`-pl`) the module name.

```
mvn -pl <module-name>
```

Doing so, relative paths shouldn't be broken and you would also take advantages of a multi-module build behavior for a single build, e.g. resolving inter-module dependencies locally via source code (because from the root `pom.xml` file Maven knowns if a certain dependency is a module or not) and not via maven dependencies (because when building directly a module, Maven doesn't have knowledge of other modules and would try to resolve inter-module dependencies like any other dependency, looking at local cache and repository and potentially not picking up latest code).

Comment: The `.mvn/jvm.config` is read during the run of the mvn script. At this time the command line is not parsed cause Maven has not been started at all. You know that defining JVM options and starting a JVM and overwriting an option would need a restart of the JVM cause the options can't be overwritten in general for a started JVM? Furthermore at the time of reading the `.mvn/jvm.config` Maven has not been started so there is no build phase running ? Maybe you can give more details on what you think might be usefull here? Or best would be to better discuss this on the user/dev list?

Comment: @khmarbaise the "if any required" actually pointed at that, that may be the feature is already complete and doesn't need additional behaviors. I knew (guessed) how it works and that's why my answer explains the impossibility for this use case or other potential use cases. Thanks for confirming them.